# Open and killing processes on mac

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

Opened program doesnt shutdown when called upon with terminate() on macOS.

I tried to open an external file through python, and then closing it. Everything seems to be working except for killing the process (application) on macOS. How to kill it?

```
prog = subprocess.Popen(['open', FileName])
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
         prog.terminate()
         break
```

Answer (score 1):

Not so easy.

In mac, the `open` command will dig up the system to find an application to launch your file, which means it will fork-exec another executable as a new process. Once it is done, the `open` command will terminate while leaving the other process run (in the background, as orphaned process).

So using the `subprocess` context, you will see the process ID of `open` but not the process ID of the child process that `open` launched. Moreover, consider the case that `open` launches a directory, which on Mac it will be opened as a new window on Finder. Then you have no new process ID created! Similarly for other files if the application invoked already running before you called `open` and it prefers to open the new file in new *tabs* of existing process instead.

In your situation, if you want a better control, probably you need to figure out the right application to open your file, and launch it directly instead of relying on `open`.

**Edit**:

This is the [man page](https://ss64.com/osx/open.html) of open. You may use some switch to make open running until the child process terminates and so on. But still, I am not sure you can kill the child processes by killing open (whether or not that succeed depends on a lot of factors). Probably you need to figure out the process IDs of the child processes and kill them directly.

Comment: Guess I'll have to find another solution. Thanks anyway :).